# Eclipse Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to develop android application and it always gone well, but today it's giving problems.

When i try to open eclipse it show me this message `"Failed to create the java virtual machine. Error occurred during initialization of VM. Could not reserve enough space for object heap"`

**This is my eclipse.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1336m 
-Xmx1336m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

I tried to change `"256m"` in `"512m"` but it still doesn't work. I tried to restart but nothing. I tried to change the `-XX:MaxPermSize=512M` value, but nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you're going the wrong way with your logic. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642184/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-to-start-jvm), or any of the many same questions here.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine/21189240#21189240

Answer (score 2):

**Just add your JDK path in windows environment variable.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open `eclipse.ini` and change the following variables.

For `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`, try changing your required Java version to **1.6**.

Memory-related defaults (as of Eclipse 3.4):

- `-Xms40m`
- `-Xmx256m`
- `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Recommended settings for Android development:

- `-Xms128m`
- `-Xmx512m`
- `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

If everything else fails you can just delete or **rename** `eclipse.ini` and let the IDE handle everything. I strongly suggest looking for a current replacement for your `eclipse.ini` and reading up on how to configure the [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Closed all the other memory intensive application in my windows7. And tried to
open eclipse. This worked for me, and I found it on similar question here [Stackoverflow-eclipse failed to create JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine/21693578#21693578).