# Failed to create Java virtual machine using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My installation of Eclipse reports error that it failed to create a Java virtual machine although I use it daily and I didn't change anything.

My *eclipse.ini* file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: When do you get the error, on startup? What is the exact message you get?

Comment: have you tried the solution in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317640/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine?rq=1 same error message and very close configuration.

Comment: Well that's weird. Now it's not showing the error and opened very well without changing anything :) 
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Just add your JDK path in windows environment variable.

or

Open eclipse.ini file and Change the vmargs sizes to
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

or

In your eclipse.ini file

Add -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw
at beginning of your eclipse.ini
//make sure you have same directory structure

And then remove 256m which is below the line --launcher.XXMaxPermSize. It will work.